# R + Import picture in a graph panel

Tags: r, graphics

I have a three-element (nrow=1, ncol=3) panel, with a single caption across, to illustrate a point. Two elements are graphs. The third one has to be a picture, which I need to import from public sources. Can you guide me on how to import this picture? Many thanks.